# window.scrollBy() function not working when component mount

Tags: reactjs

I want to store previous offset of infinite list.my way is storing offset when user scrolling into sessionStorage, then use it whenever user back to this component.But when i navigate to another component then back to here, window.scrollBy() not working.Am i missing something or wrong somewhere of my code?

all my code

```
const Home = () => {
  ...
  const navigateToChat = useNavigate();
  const handleNavigateToChat = () => {
    navigateToChat("/chat");
  };

  //Check if user scrolled then get this value to for window.scrollBy()
  useEffect(()=>{
    const handleGetOffset = () => {
      const scrolledIndex = sessionStorage.getItem("scrolledIndex")
      scrolledIndex &&  window.scrollBy(0,scrolledIndex)
        console.log(scrolledIndex)
    };
    handleGetOffset ()
  },[])

  //Get yOffset then storing into sessionStorage
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      sessionStorage.setItem("scrolledIndex",window.scrollY)
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () =>{
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
    }
  },[]);

  const handleFindingUser = async () => {
    //Get data from server
    ...
  };
  ...
  return (
   <InfiniteScroll
            dataLength={users.length} //This is important field to render the next data
            next={handleFindingUser}
            hasMore={hasMore}
            loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
            endMessage={
              <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                <b>Yay! You have seen it all</b>
              </p>
            }
          >
            {users.map((user) => {
              return (
                <div
             
                  key={user.userId}
                  id={user.nickName}
                  className="d-flex"
                  style={{ margin: 12 }}
                >
                  <p>{user.nickName}</p>
                  <Button
                    onClick={handleNavigateToChat}
                    variant="info"
                    style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}
                  >
                    Chat Now
                  </Button>
                </div>
              );
            })}
   </InfiniteScroll>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

have a nice day, everyone!

Comment: are you sure it doesn't go to loading mode when you scroll and all data are available? I mean maybe it scrolls to where you said but because it's not rendering yet it couldn't get it. for example, it should scroll to 4000 and all the page is 2000 so it scroll and the view is showing loading.

Comment: i'm sure. i tested by assigned value over 100 but it still doesn't work. all my code is right?

Comment: @ghazalkhaki but when i changing value then save(ctrl + S), it scrolled, i don't know why.

Comment: I couldn't check your code, otherwise, you tell me what UI framework is using your `InfiniteScroll` component, to check your code in stackblitz

Comment: but it seems the scroll is going where is not loaded yet. that was my first guess. data in this page is asynchrony, right?

Comment: @ghazalkhaki https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component

Comment: @ghazalkhaki yes, i get it from server.